# Html change text of <a> tag

Tags: jquery, html, .net, razor, kendo-ui

I currently am working with the following  tag which is rendered as a button with only an icon on it.
I would like this to be the icon followed by the words `Export PDF`.

Normally, I would not go about creating the button like this but I am using a Kendo control which produce the button for me. Once rendered the button looks as follows:

```
<a href="" role="button" class="k-tool k-group-start k-group-end" 
    unselectable="on" title="Export PDF">
    <span unselectable="on" class="k-tool-icon k-pdf"></span>
    <span class="k-tool-text">Export PDF</span>
</a>
```

I am trying to use JQuery to inject my wanted text into the element as follows:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.k-tool-icon').text("Export PDF");
        });
</script>
```

however this does not change anything. I still get the button with only an icon.

Edit: Below is the C# MVC kendo editor that is rendering the above posted html:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Editor()
      .Name("editor")
      .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:900px" })
      .Pdf(pdf => pdf
          .Margin(20, 20, 20, 20)
          .ProxyURL(Url.Action("Pdf_Export_Save", "Editor"))
      )
      .Tools(tools => tools
          .Clear()
          .Pdf()
      )
      .Value(@<text>
        <code>
            @Html.Raw(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Model.ReportString))
        </code>
    </text>)
    )
```

Comment: Works for me https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/f0pcyx1q/

Comment: The icon is probably using a text-replacement technique. What's wrong with styling the .k-tool-text span?

Comment: @j08691 maybe it is working for you since you're not actually using a kendo editor? I'm not sure. However it definitely doesn't work for me

Comment: @moopet can you provide an example I'm not sure what you're getting at

Comment: You should update the tags on your question then with whatever Kendo tools apply. As I noted, the code you supplied works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to replace the content  it would be much faster to use native DOM

In the code sample you gave above you have the same text on the button before and after.

```
Before: <span class="k-tool-text">Export PDF</span>
After: $('.k-tool-icon').text("Export PDF");
```

---

```
// Use Native DOM for better performace
$(document).ready(function () {
    document.querySelector('.k-tool-icon').textContent = `Export PDF`;
});
```

But anyway the code you showed here is working.

Comment: I've posted the code for the kendo control I am using also. This must be the reason that it is not working for me but is working for others here who are directly using the html produced by kendo

Answer (score 0):

@peggy, probably you problem is that the kendo process is delaying to much after the document is ready, than when it try to add the text the element generated by kendo still does not exists.

Try to add the `$('.k-tool-icon').text("Export PDF");` on some event when Kendo is already finished to process;